# Was the member 'Tick' always supposed to be a part of the colony?

Tags: the-colony

In season 2 of Discovery's 'The Colony' later in the series a man named Tick reveals himself to the rest of the group. This brings their number up to 10, which is the same number that the first season had. The voice on the screen said that Tick had been there since the very beginning.

Was he supposed to be a part of the colony and just struck it out on his own until he decided to get involved?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the introduction of Tick was to spice things up. The 2nd season was far less interesting than the first, so the producers wanted to liven up the show in an attempt to garner more viewers. They wanted to introduce Tick and the "new settlement" that they eventually raided just for ratings. I read an article about it shortly after how it wasn't planned from the start, but they had to add a catalyst or risk having falling ratings.